# Permanently update linux distro .iso file in pen

Tags: apt, kali-linux, iso, distributions

I have a kali 2.0 (last released version) on a pen and run it on a virtual machine with allocated memory on my hard drive. However, even though this kali distribution is the last version available I still need to run apt-get update every time I boot the machine (basically all packages, from armitage to burp, hosts and nikto etc etc etc...) so I was wondering how exactly could I permanently update the iso? I tried running it in all modes, from forensics to encrypted persistence or regular but it never saves anything... Any idea on how I could do this? TYVM.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the original ISO file burned to the pen, so when you load the pen drive, the original ISO files are untarred/unzipped. This means that no matter what updates you make to the pen, it is not saved to the original file being untarred/unzipped and your changes will be lost when you reload the pen drive.

A solution to this would be to actually install Kali Linux to the pen itself, rather than just burning an ISO image to it.